# Best way to find server IP in local network with android client

Tags: android, reactive-programming, rx-java2, executorservice, android-workmanager

Suppose that we have a server in local network that we want to find IP address with a REST API call request.

I tried many solutions, but which one of these is efficient and fast way and how to use it?

- Using RxJava
- Using ExecutorService
- Using parallelStream
- Using WorkManager
- Using Using for loop :)
- Or something else?

My usage:

```
 Observable.range(1, 254)
            .flatMap(val ->
                    Observable.just(val)
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                            .map(i -> performRequest(i))
                            .filter(r -> r != 0)
            )
            .subscribe(new Observer<Integer>() {

                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Integer index) {
                    System.out.println("Server Index IP: " + index);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    System.out.println("&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& COMPLETED &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&");
                }
            });
```

And which one of below ways, is the best implementation of network request for integration with above way:

- Using Retrofit
- Using Fast Android Networking
- Using simple HttpURLConnection
- Or something else?

My Request:

```
private Integer performRequest(int index) {
    GetHandShakeInfo response = null;
    String serverIP = networkIP + "." + index;
    requestSum = requestSum + 1;
    counter.incrementAndGet();
    System.out.println("*** Network Request of IP " + serverIP + " on " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    try {
        URL url = new URL(AddressHelper.INSTANCE.getLocalServerHandshakeAddress(serverIP));
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setConnectTimeout(2000);
        if (connection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Success HandshakeRequest : " + url.toString());
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
            for (String line; (line = r.readLine()) != null; ) {
                total.append(line);
            }
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            response = gson.fromJson(total.toString(), GetHandShakeInfo.class);
            Log.d(TAG, "#Success, server response: " + response.toString());
            return index;
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "#Failed HandshakeRequest : " + url.toString());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "#Exception HandshakeRequest : " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

## Request Schema: http://192.168.30.xxx/api/handshake

## xxx range: 1 to 254

- we want to find the xxx on this local network.

Comment: How would your rest api call look like? And finding the ip address of what?

Comment: @blackapps , i add more description on post.

Comment: `tried many solutions,` Well then you could tell us which is 'efficient' and 'fast' and 'how you used it' i think.

Comment: @blackapps , i means that which one is best solution for this problem ?

Comment: I think that you are the one to tell such if you tried them all.

Comment: @blackapps i dont tried all of them, but i put one of them.

Comment: Are you launching 254 requests at the same time? And what is the ip of the client when you start! If it is 100 then i would not start at 3 unless the server is always the first to connect. You forgot to mention how much time that approach needs to discover the server.

Comment: I would just take a Socket and just try to connect. Thats all.

Comment: @blackapps , i use the rxjava for these requests so it pass the requests to approximately 10 threads. so all of requests dosnt called at the same time.

Comment: @blackapps Also you suppose that client and server are at the same network domain.

Comment: @blackapps Also with this way, it take 45 second.

Comment: At which ip do you finally find the server? And what was the ip of the client  then? Indeed i suppose the client is on the same network.

Comment: If you set the timeout at two seconds and you need 45 seconds then you tried at least 22 ip's. That is a lot. What kind of lan are you in with so many clients?

Comment: @blackapps I think you dont get my question. In some local network we have an server that we dont know the ip address. so one or more client wants to know the server ip address. after finding the ip address they can call some request api .

Comment: I understand all. You can deduce that from my questions ;-). But you are not answering my questions.

Comment: You suppose that the client ip address is 192.168.30.121. is there any not answered question ?

Comment: `You suppose that the client ip address is 192.168.30.121` I do not suppose anything. Do you mean: `The client ip address is 192.168.30.121` ? And there are more questions/remarks. Please reread my comments.